A reductive group is the complexification of a compact subgroup even if not connected?
The definition of a linear algebraic complex reductive group is sometimes using the connectedness hypothesis for the complex algebraic group sometimes not.
Here I use the following definition : a complex affine linear algebraic group $G$ is said to be reductive if the connected component of the identity of its unipotent radical is trivial. I am aware that the linear hypothesis is somewhat redundant.
Is the well known following theorem still true without any connectedness hypothesis (for the complex algebraic groups or the real compact ones, since being connected or irreducible is the same for the algebraic group)?

There is an equivalence of categories between the category of smooth
representations of a compact real Lie group and and the category of
algebraic representations of a complex linear algebraic reductive
groups.

Or the following theorem?

A linear complex algebraic group is reductive if and only if it has an
algebraic compact real form, which is then a maximal compact real Lie
group

Or the following one?

The complexification of a compact real Lie group is a reductive linear
algebraic group

The only place I found these theorems without any hypothesis on the connectedness is in Lie Groups and Algebraic Groups by Onishchik & Vinberg, but their definition of reductiveness is based on the reductiveness of the Lie algebra, which does not seem clearly to exclude the case of the $(\mathbb{C}, +)$ group.
I would also like if the hypothesis is necessary a counter-example and if not a good reference.
Edit
Reposted from MathSE https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4963922/is-connectedness-necessary-for-a-reductive-group-to-be-the-complexification-of-a
Edit Actually in the book Representations of Compact Lie Groups of Tammo tom Dieck and Theodor Bröcker, a clear proof of the last theorem mentioned above is given without any hypothesis of connectivity, in cap. III.8.

There is no equivalence of categories between compact real Lie groups and complex linear algebraic reductive groups. Just consider automorphism groups on each side. The equivalence of categories is only between the categories of representations.

@WillSawin Oopss ... you are right I edited my question!

Please wait a few days between reposting between MathSE and MO to give people time to answer on the first site, and please also link between the two questions so people can easily check if one is answered before answering the other.

@WillSawin Once again you are right! sorry for my mistake. Will edit the two questions with the link.

If $G$ is any (real) Lie group with finitely many components, then it is still true (Mostow 1955) that compact maximal subgroups meet all connected components and are all conjugate. In case $G$ is complex reductive and $K$ is maximal compact, then it might hold that $G$ is the complexification of $K$ (in the sense that complex reps of $K$ uniquely extend to $G$); uniqueness of extensions of reps is clear from Mostow's result plus the connected case, but I'm not sure about existence.

@YCor A complex reductive linear algebraic group has a finite number of irreducible components. The result in the book of Tammo tom Dieck mentioned in my question show that the existence of extension of reps is clear. So is it sufficient to answer my question? If you think so, would you mind transforming your comment into an answer so that I can give you the bounty?

@YCor To extend a representation of a disconnected reductive group $G$ from the maximal compact $K$, first extend from the identity component of $K$ the identity component of $G$, then induce to $G$. Restricting to $K$ you get an induction of restriction which has the original representation as a summand, and Hom-spaces over $K$ and $G$ are equal so you can pick out the original representation as a summand over $G$.

@WillSawin simple and clear, but I thought the result of chapter III.6 of the book of Tammi Tom Dieck was sufficient to demonstrate existence. Am I mistaken? In any case you or YCor should give an answer to my question. If you don’t a catastrophic and frustrating event will happen: the hard earned bounty points will disappear into nothingness.

@WillSawin I'm happy if you post an answer.

@brunoh I didn't check the reference to that book, but you said it answers your third question, which I interpreted as a statement of the form "For each compact real Lie group there exists a complex reductive group such that ..." and not "For each reductive linear algebraic group there exists a compact group such that...." which YCor's reference was about. What's the result in the book say exactly?

@WillSawin Actually, the result of III.8 of this book is the building of the complexification of a compact group, mainly using Tannaka-Krein duality, and proving that it is a reductive complex algebraic group, with every smooth representation of the compact one extending to an algebraic one of its complexifciation, without apparently any connectedness hypothesis on the compact group.

@brunoh So then I guess it doesn't handle the main part of YCor's and my answer, which is the existence of a compact group whose complexification (in the sense of Tannaka-Krein duality) is a given reductive group.

@WillSawin so my comment was that to check in your answer the fact that every smooth representation of $K$ extend to an algebraic one of $G$ is done in this book. But I like your direct and to the point approach (even if the algebraicity of the extension was not obvious for me). In any case I accepted your answer and gave you the bounty.

@WillSawin You are absolutely right. The key part of your and YCor answer was a consequence of Mostow theorem. I was just talking about a small step in your development.

Let $G$ be a complex, not necessarily connected reductive group and let $K$ be a maximal compact subgroup.
There is a natural function from algebraic representations of $G$ to continuous representations of $K$. Let's check it is an equivalence.
We already know the statement for the identity component $G^0$ of $G$ and the identity component $K^0$ of $K$.
YCor points out that Mostow proved in 1955 that $K$ meets every component of $G$, i.e. that the natural map $K/ K^0 \to G/G^0$ is an isomorphism.
The function from representations of $G$ to representations of $K$ is faithful. To check it is essentially surjective, i.e. that the natural map $\operatorname{Hom}_G(V,W) \to \operatorname{Hom}_K(V,W)$ is an isomorphism, we observe that
$$\operatorname{Hom}_G(V,W) = ( \operatorname{Hom}_{G^0}(V,W))^{G/G^0} = ( \operatorname{Hom}_{G^0}(V,W))^{K/K^0}=  ( \operatorname{Hom}_{K^0}(V,W))^{K/K^0}= \operatorname{Hom}_K(V,W)$$
where the first and last equalities are obvious and the middle two use the two facts we checked.
To check that it is faithful, i.e. that every representation of $K$ extends to a representation of $G$, let $V$ be a representation of $K$. As a representation of $G^0$, we know by the connected case that $V$ extends to a representation of $G^0$. Then the restriction of $\operatorname{Ind}_{G^0}^G V$ to $K$ is $\operatorname{Ind}_{K^0}^K V$ and contains $V$ as a summand over $K$. The idempotent projector to this summand is a $K$-invariant homomorphism, hence a $G$-invariant homomorphism, so this summand is a $G$-invariant subrepresentation and in particular is a representation of $G$ extending $V$, as desired.
To reverse this process, passing from a compact group to a complex group, we may simply take the Tannakian group of the category of finite-dimensional representations of $K$, which has the equivalence of categories property by definition. This is how I would define the complexification in the disconnected context, although there may be other definitions which are also helpful.

@YCor's comment pointing out the Mostow result.  See also In any Lie group with finitely many connected components, does there exist a finite subgroup which meets every component?. \ That $K$ meets every component of $G$ implies that $K/K^0 \to G/G^0$ is surjective.  Why is it an isomorphism? \ Is it a priori obvious that the category of representations of a compact group is the category of representations of a complex group, i.e., that it has a Tannakian group?
